# Invertable matrix representation for 2nd order differentiation or integration of non-equidistant data

Tags: integration, matrices, definite-integrals, numerical-methods

I am looking for a second order differentiation-matrix to numerically differentiate a non-equidistant data vector using simple matrix multiplication.

$$
f(t)=y=\begin{bmatrix}f(t_1)\\ \vdots\\ f(t_n)\end{bmatrix},
\Delta t_i=t_{i+1}-t_i,
My=\left(\frac{d}{d t}\right)^2f(t),M=?
$$

However this matrix needs to be **invertable** and should result in a good estimate for double integration in that regard as well. For that reason an invertable second order integration-matrix answers the same question.

$$
(M)^{-1}y=\int\int f(t) dtdt
$$

I tried a number of approaches but have trouble with the boundary cases. To illustrate the issues here are some examples:

- **Trapezoidal double integration:** The matrix representation starts with an all zero row, which makes it singular and as such, not invertable. Using a minimal value for the first entry instead results in a good estimate for the 1st order derivative, but with the 2nd order differentiation $T^{-1}$ the estimate heavily oscilates around the actual values.
  $$
  T=
  \begin{bmatrix}
      10^{-50}  &     0                         & 0 & 0 & \dots \\
      \frac{\Delta t_1}2 & \frac{\Delta t_1}2            & 0 & 0 & \dots \\
      \frac{\Delta t_1}2 & \frac{\Delta t_1+\Delta t_2}2 & \frac{\Delta t_2}2 & 0 & \dots \\
      \frac{\Delta t_1}2 & \frac{\Delta t_1+\Delta t_2}2 & \frac{\Delta t_2+\Delta t_3}2 & \frac{\Delta t_3}2 &   \\
      \vdots &\vdots &\vdots &  & \ddots
  \end{bmatrix}
  $$
  and $M_{doubleInt}=T^2$. So $T^{-1}$ gives good results, but $M_{doubleInt}^{-1}$ does not.
- **[Double central difference](https://mathformeremortals.wordpress.com/2013/01/12/a-numerical-second-derivative-from-three-points/):** The results depend heavily on the choice for the `?`s.
  $$
  C=
  \begin{bmatrix}
      ? & ? & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
      \frac2{\Delta t_1 (\Delta t_1+ \Delta t_2)} & -\frac2{\Delta t_1 \Delta t_2} & -\frac2{\Delta t_2 (\Delta t_1 + \Delta t_2)} & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
      0 & \frac2{\Delta t_2 (\Delta t_2+ \Delta t_3)} & -\frac2{\Delta t_2 \Delta t_3} & -\frac2{\Delta t_3 (\Delta t_2 + \Delta t_3)} & \dots & 0 \\
      \vdots &  &\ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
      0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & ? & ?
  \end{bmatrix}
  $$
- **Back difference**: This is the only one that worked so far with both $B^2$ and $(B^2)^{-1}$, despite having poor accuracy compared to the other two approaches.

$$
B = \begin{bmatrix}
    ?                    & 0                  & 0                  &0& \\
    -\frac1{\Delta t_1}  & \frac1{\Delta t_1} & 0                  &0&\dots\\
    0                    & -\frac1{\Delta t_2}& \frac1{\Delta t_2} &0& \\
    0                    & 0                  & -\frac1{\Delta t_3}& \frac1{\Delta t_3}& \\
                         & \vdots             &                    &\ddots &\ddots
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Note that all `?`s are undetermined by the common descriptions of the approaches. I tested them with variable numbers, but I could not find a good setting for those edge cases. If one could find a good setup for those, it might also solve my problem.

Is there a better matrix that provides good estimates *and* is invertable?

### Edit:

My question really is simple but I find it hard to express it with the correct mathematical wording since most terms are highly ambiguous. They seem to be rarely used in this way, too, so I could need some help to reword my question.

Comment: There are infinitely many derivatives for a given function which is the reason why a differentiation matrix is *always* singular (because it should give zero from any constant input). You should improve your question to explain what you really want to do.

Comment: @Tom-Tom Thank you for your reply, but I don't really understand your comment. In case this is the misunderstanding: I am not looking for a derivative of a matrix of function values, but a matrix that *produces* the derivative of a data vector without knowing the underlying function. If this was unclear, may you help me reword my question?